# How do I find how much a battery pack can charge my device?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charging, charger

I have a Dell laptop with these battery specifications from HWID HWMONITOR
[image]

I want to buy a powerbank, and saw there are many 20k mAh/30k mAh batteries, as described by sellers. How can I check how many times the 20k/30k power bank can charge my device from 0 to 100% or 0 to 80% before the power bank empties?

Comment: I am not sure if measuring battery capacity is a computer question under SU guidelines

Comment: You have to know what's the voltage of the powerbank batteries to roughly estimate this.

Comment: By trying it. Absolutely no other way. There's too many variables, power doesn't just "magically" go from battery A to battery B.

Answer (score 3):

**If** the vendor is honest, it's not too difficult to calculate.

- The computer has a "39994 mWh" battery, that is, about 40 W-h (i.e., can supply ~40 watts for 1 hour). A full charge would have to provide *at least* 40 W-h, and a bit more, because charging is not 100% efficient.
- The rating of **battery packs** seems to me a bit deceptive: they often give the capacity in mA-h, without mentioning that the cell inside is ~3.7 volts, in most cases. A 20,000 mA-h (20 A-h) 3.7 V charger could provide ~20 * 3.5 (one never lets a battery completely discharge, lest it be ruined), ~70 W-h.
- *If* that 20 A-h rating is honest, and allowing for inefficiency, that could fully charge your device *once*, with a dribble of energy left over.

However, many vendors are deceitful, misleading, and downright untrustworthy. One seller states its battery pack is ***1,000,000 mA-h***, because it can provide **10,000 mA-h** each time it's used, **if you recharge it 100 times!**

Checking third-party reviews from a test site, such as [Consumer Reports](https://www.consumerreports.org/cars/jump-starters/buying-guide/) can help, but be prepared for disappointment.

Comment: I never understood batteries and their physical units and what is the connection between those units.

Comment: So, do you now have a better understanding?